# abbreviations as participles

Tags: verbs, abbreviations

When an abbreviation serves as a verb, the past participle generally takes an apostrophe followed by a *d*:

*KO'd
ID'd
OD'd
OK'd*

What is the proper present participle? If

*KOing
IDing
ODing
OKing*

is correct, then why should the past participle require an elision? It seems to aid readability, so should the *-ing* form be

*KO'ng
ID'ng
OD'ng
OK'ng*

???

Comment: I would understand if you were asking about "KO'ing", but "KO'ng" is quite obviously not an option. You will be hard pressed to find a single instance of "'ng" in any book, article, or even YouTube comment.

Comment: I'm not sure why it is "obviously" not an option. In the past tense, the apostrophe takes the place of the *e* in *-ed*, but why should it do that? If *KO'ing* is correct, then why shouldn't the past tense be *KO'ed*?

Comment: @surlawda: He said that ***KO'ng*** was wrong, not _KO'ed. KO'ed_ is OK. T

Comment: Yes, thanks, I can see that. But he also didn't say that *KO'd* was wrong. Is that what you are saying?

Comment: I have seen this written as ID-ing/OD-ing etc. I can't recall previously seeing KO-ing/OK-ing.

Answer (score 1):

I gather it's OK'd and OK'ing.  Okaying and okayed are also accepted.

Since that is the generally accepted form, KO'd and KO'ing would be the correct form for KO, and OD'd and OD'ing would be the correct from for OD.